# jupyter setup i18n on exiting notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have been trying to translate jupyter notebook interface with my native language, using existing i18n implementation. I have already created translation files just like readme advised and now i want to add it to jupyter.

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/tree/master/notebook/i18n

but i can't find /notebook/i18n/ folder on my computer ( Ubuntu 16.04 ).Do i have to install jupyter one more time or can i just add translate files to already existing jupyter installation on my machine and run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled jupyter and this time i18n folder is on its place in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/notebook/i18n/i18n
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find lib_path by python:

```
import sys
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print (get_python_lib())
```

And you will find it in
`${lib_path}/notebook/i18n/`